# Crashlytics is not able to read log file

Tags: logging, crashlytics, logfile

Why am I getting `A problem occurred while reading the Crashlytics log file.` into my **logcat** (see below)? Should I ignore? I don't want to add read write permissions to my **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Logcat output:

```
04-01 23:27:12.258  28900-28920/com.playgong.stg.dbg E/Fabric﹕ A problem occurred while reading the Crashlytics log file.
    java.io.IOException: lseek failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
            at java.io.RandomAccessFile.seek(RandomAccessFile.java:603)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.QueueFile.readElement(QueueFile.java:186)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.QueueFile.forEach(QueueFile.java:425)
            at com.crashlytics.android.LogFileManager.getByteStringForLog(LogFileManager.java:162)
            at com.crashlytics.android.SessionDataWriter.writeSessionEvent(SessionDataWriter.java:187)
            at com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.writeSessionEvent(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:952)
            at com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.doWriteNonFatal(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:988)
            at com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.access$500(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:56)
            at com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler$9.run(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:368)
            at com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsExecutorServiceWrapper$1.run(CrashlyticsExecutorServiceWrapper.java:75)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:46)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:13)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: lseek failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
            at libcore.io.Posix.lseek(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.lseek(ForwardingOs.java:89)
            at java.io.RandomAccessFile.seek(RandomAccessFile.java:601)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.QueueFile.readElement(QueueFile.java:186)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.QueueFile.forEach(QueueFile.java:425)
            at com.crashlytics.android.LogFileManager.getByteStringForLog(LogFileManager.java:162)
            at com.crashlytics.android.SessionDataWriter.writeSessionEvent(SessionDataWriter.java:187)
            at com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.writeSessionEvent(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:952)
            at com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.doWriteNonFatal(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:988)
            at com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.access$500(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:56)
            at com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler$9.run(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:368)
            at com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsExecutorServiceWrapper$1.run(CrashlyticsExecutorServiceWrapper.java:75)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:46)
            at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:13)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 1):

Update Crashlytics to 2.2.3 version fixed. Like this:

```
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.3@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

Looks like issue was in 2.2.2 version and in 2.2.3 it was fixed.